# R: Why digest(algo = sha1) produces different answer to sha1()

Tags: r, hash

```r
# what I need
x <- 111111
consistent_output <- hash_function(as.character(x))
```

I understand there must be a good reason for this, but it is confusing to me why in the `digest` library `sha1()` and `digest(,algo=sha1)` produce different results. I need to choose method which will give the same results on all machines. I need to pass six to ten  digits as character string and get always the same output from a one-way hash function.

1. Is there a possibility that results might be still different if R script is done on 32 bit system vs 64bit system? I write scripts on a 64bit Linux machine, but they may well need to be executed on various Windows computers.
2. How to explain the different results below, and is there a difference in future-proof_ness if for my script I choose either `digest(x,algo = "sha1")` or `sha1(x)`?

```r
library(digest)

> digest("111111", algo = "sha1")
[1] "f807e8107b0ee536b79044938ac2497845f43c71"
> sha1("111111")
[1] "e6975dc20e721b2a5cfa6f0d834b2bf8287ab592"
```

When I say future-proofness, I mean - if I run the same function on the same input 10 years from now, I would wish to get the same output.

Many thanks, and apologies if my question is too simple - I am not from a computer science background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sha1` function adds attributes to the object that you pass in so it knows exactly what settings were used to create the hash. These attributes are then serialized with the data as well.

The `digest()` function also serializes data. This means that the object as it's stored in R is preserved, not just the value itself. You can see the serialized value with

```
serialize("111111", NULL)
#  [1] 58 0a 00 00 00 03 00 04 02 01 00 03 05 00 00 00 00 05 55 54 46 2d 38 00 00 00 10 00
# [29] 00 00 01 00 04 00 09 00 00 00 06 31 31 31 31 31 31
```

So there are a lot more bytes there than just the string value. If you are just working with string values, you can skip the serialization step

```
digest("111111", algo = "sha1", serialize = FALSE)
[1] "3d4f2bf07dc1be38b20cd6e46949a1071f9d0e3d"
```

That will match what you would get at the linux command line

```
echo -n "111111" | sha1sum
3d4f2bf07dc1be38b20cd6e46949a1071f9d0e3d  -
```

and also matches online calculators like http://www.sha1-online.com/

So if you need compatibility with non-R systems, then I would recommend `digest()` with `serialize=FALSE` since values might be serialized differently in other languages. If you only have to worry about R, then it would probably be safer to use `sha1` keeping in mind that it's including extra info in the object that affects the resulting hash

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot @MrFlick. Would it not be the the most portable and safe then to always use `serialize = FALSE`? I have been thinking about it and if it is to get a digest of a simple string or number, then there is no need for serialization. But I can see that for more complex R objects serialization may be required.

Comment: Yes. I thought I said that in the answer. If you want compatibility with non R systems, use `serialize=FALSE`. But string are only simple if they are ASCII values, otherwise you have to worry about encodings and normalization forms; and with numbers you may have to worry about endianness and floating point representations if you are using different systems. You just need to be careful when converting values to bytes for hashing.